# How to declare a self-referential template typedef

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Here's a small example which is substantially similar to what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    const char * str;
};

typedef std::pair<float, float> fpair;

//typedef std::vector<boost::variant<int, fpair, foo, vlist>> vlist;
// ^ No...

//typedef std::vector<boost::variant<int, fpair, foo, boost::recursive_wrapper<vlist>>> vlist;
// ^ No...

//template <typename T = vlist<T> >
//using vlist = std::vector<boost::variant<int, fpair, foo, boost::recursive_wrapper<vlist>>>;
// ^ No...

template <typename T = vlist<T> >
using vlist = std::vector<boost::variant<int, fpair, foo, boost::recursive_wrapper<T>>>;
// Still no?

int main () {
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
}
```

The error I get with gcc 4.8 is:

```
test.cpp:12:33: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘vlist’
template <typename T = typename vlist<T>>
                                ^
test.cpp:12:33: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘vlist’
```

The error with clang 3.6 is:

```
test.cpp:12:24: error: unknown type name 'vlist'
template <typename T = vlist<T>>
                       ^
test.cpp:12:29: error: expected ',' or '>' in template-parameter-list
template <typename T = vlist<T>>
                            ^
test.cpp:12:32: error: expected unqualified-id
template <typename T = vlist<T>>
                               ^
3 errors generated.
```

(Edit: actually these errors are from slightly different versions of the above code, but they all give quite similar messages)

I looked at these earlier, slightly different questions, I'm still stumped:

[How to declare a self referencing template type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997730/how-to-declare-a-self-referencing-template-type)

[How to properly declare a self-referencing template type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208720/how-to-properly-declare-a-self-referencing-template-type)

[Boost Fusion adapt declaration for a templated self referential structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593733/boost-fusion-adapt-declaration-for-a-templated-self-referential-structure)

Does anyone know a trick for this, or is there some reason I'm not aware of that the compiler inherently isn't able to do this?

Comment: `typename T = vlist<T>` what do you *want* this to mean?

Comment: so in short I guess I got confused when reading this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208720/how-to-properly-declare-a-self-referencing-template-type

Comment: Old skool solution: `struct vlist { std::vector<boost::variant<int, fpair, foo, vlist>> val; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just want [`boost::make_recursive_variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive.recursive-variant):

```
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    const char* str;
};

typedef std::pair<float, float> fpair;

typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
    int,
    fpair,
    foo,
    std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>
>::type vlist;

int main() {
    std::vector<vlist> vec;
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(fpair{1.0f, 2.0f});

    vlist v2(vec);
}
```

Comment: Did you actually compile this code? I am surprisingly struggling to make it work on GCC.

Comment: Show the whole compilable example.

Comment: I find this dog dialogue quite funny :p

Comment: thanks, I guess this is probably the easiest way to do it (compiles for me on gcc and clang)

Comment: Damn, I just got confused and wrote `boost::recursive_wrapper_` instead of `boost::recursive_variant_`.